# Proving smoothness from fast decay of Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, fourier-analysis, smooth-functions

I have seen some similar questions around, but they use a slightly different assumption than mine. Furthermore, I am trying to figure out the details of the proof, and I got what I believe is a mistake.

I am trying to prove the following.

Define the function

$$f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} c_k e^{2 \pi i kx}$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume that $\forall k, \ |c_k| \leq ae^{-bk^2}$ for positive real numbers $a,b$.

Then, $f$ is continuous, and infinitely differentiable. Also, find an expression for $f'(x)$.

For continuity I just used well-known inequalities. Assume $x \to x_0$:

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)| = \left| \sum_k c_k \left( e^{2 \pi i k x} - e^{2 \pi i k x_0} \right) \right| \leq \sum_k \left| c_k \left( e^{2 \pi i k x} - e^{2 \pi i k x_0} \right) \right| = \sum_k |c_k| \left| e^{2 \pi i k x} - e^{2 \pi i k x_0} \right| \leq \sum_k ae^{-bk^2} \left| e^{2 \pi i k x} - e^{2 \pi i k x_0} \right| \to0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{   as  } \ \ x \to x_0$$

Now, let's just try to prove that $f$ is once-differentiable.

If I try to do it by the definition of limits, I get

$$f'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sum_k c_k\left( e^{2 \pi i k (x+h)} - e^{2 \pi i k x} \right)}{h} $$

and I can now just put the limit "through" the sum which is basically just obtaining the limit that gives the derivative of the exponential function, which is known to be $\frac{d}{dx}e^{rx} = re^{rx}$

So this gives $$\sum_k c_k \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{2 \pi i k (x+h)} - e^{2 \pi i k x}}{h} = \sum_k c_k(2\pi i k)e^{2 \pi i kx}$$

Similarly, for proving that it is infinitely differentiable I can do that by induction and use the same procedure as above to show that the $n$th derivative is just

$$\sum_k c_k (2 \pi i k)^n e^{2 \pi i k x}$$

My problem is that I never used the assumption that the coefficients are rapidly decaying for the differentiability proofs, so I am thinking I got something wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: What did you think gave you the right to exchange limits and an infinite sum?

Comment: You're right! I need uniform convergence right?

Comment: Fast decay insures the formal sums that you get by differentiating the original series converge absolutely hence uniformly so you can integrate them and show they are indeed what you need

Comment: You won’t exactly get uniform convergence, but that’s the same sort of reasoning.